# Roo Script - howto change pk name from "id"

Tags: spring-roo

i got a script who create jpa entitys. All pk-column is named id.

what i got now is:

```
entity jpa --class bla.Test
field string --notNull --fieldName email --clas bla.Test
```

will create

```
CREATE TABLE test {
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
  email MEDIUMTEXT
}
```

i like to have test_id as pk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

entity jpa --class bla.Test --identifierField test_id